# Возможна ли в предложении подобная вариация запятых?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Недавно пришлось столкнуться с текстом произведения М. Пришвина "Кладовая солнца", и одно предложение, признаюсь честно, заставило задуматься.
В оригинальном варианте оно пишется так: "У нас в Блудовом болоте эти холмы песчаные, покрытые высоким бором, называют боринами".

Но вот возникло два вопроса:
1. Можно ли расставить знаки препинания по-другому?
2. Правомерно ли отсутствие запятой перед словом "песчаные"?

Что касается второго вопроса, то запятую хочется поставить, потому что эти определения являются уточняющими. 
Вот, кстати говоря, мой вариант расстановки: "У нас, в Блудовом болоте, эти холмы, песчаные, покрытые высоким бором, называют боринами".
Буду рада, если вы объясните наличие или отсутствие того или иного знака.

Comment: Вот в этом издании  тоже поставили запятую  (3-я глава) http://www.e-reading.mobi/chapter.php/1005007/99/Slovo_o_soldate.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Варианты и с запятой, и без неё возможны. Правда, наличие запятой меняет интонацию и смысл предложения.

Вариант без запятой не только возможен, но  и желателен: нужно учитывать ритм и мелодику текста сказки-были. Благодаря отсутствию запятой фраза звучит более напевно, плавно, как и положено в сказке.

Таких предложений с инверсией, в которых согласованное необособленное определение стоит после определяемого слова, создавая эффект сказочного, неторопливого повествования,  в произведении немало: *Им всем хотелось сказать одно только какое-то слово прекрасное; И как будто они тогда тоже обрадуются, как будто тогда они тоже все подхватят чудесное слово, слетевшее с языка человеческого.*

**Вынуждена дополнить свой ответ.**

**Розенталь** (о нераспространённых определениях, стоящих после определяемого существительного, уже имеющего впереди определение): "...Однако **относительные** прилагательные в роли определений к словосочетаниям **могут и не обособляться**, если они имеют **логическое ударение**".

*Холмы песчаные* - словосочетание, в котором на относительное прилагательное *песчаные* падает логическое ударение. Запятую перед ним не ставим.

***В тихий вечер зимний в маленьком доме у Пречистенских ворот мы сидели за чаем (Цвет.).***

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласна (_вариант без запятой не только возможен, но и желателен..._). Думаю, что предложение не нуждается в "улучшениях". О Пришвине-писателе — "Великий Язычник"; о его произведениях — "проявление красоты слога и гармонии сюжета".

Comment: «У нас в Блудовом болоте эти холмы песчаные, покрытые высоким бором... «  Читаешь и думаешь, что это первое предложение в составе ССП. А где же второе? Наверное, местоимение пропущено, дальше должно быть так: «их называют боринами».  Нет, скорее запятая при обособлении пропущена. Вот теперь нормальное предложение, такое напевное, сказочное, вполне себе на уровне.  Не нужна запятая?!  Что-то я сильно сомневаюсь. Как-то по другому я представляла сказочность и напевность, здесь же мне видится только предложение, которое читается и понимается с трудом.

Comment: Да, прав был Даль, которого мы тут недавно обсуждали. А говорил он вот о чем: «Заметим, однако, что толковать и объяснять пословицы надо крайне осторожно, чтобы не обратить этого дела в свою игрушку. Особенно опасно искать ученым взглядом того, чего бы найти хотелось..." Здесь мне видится похожая ситуация..Иногда мы так уверены в красоте слога писателя,  что и случайную ошибку (возможно, редакторскую) готовы посчитать за художественное достоинство.

Comment: @Екатерина Каштанова  Непонятно, зачем Вы приводите примеры предложений, которые не имеют ничего общего с тем, которое мы рассматриваем? Инверсия определения? Кто же будет спорить, это очень известный прием, особенно в стихотворной речи, да и в прозе, конечно, встречается. Можно привести десяток примеров, можно больше привести, да что от этого изменится? В этих предложениях это средство художественной выразительности, а в предложении с другой грамматикой и структурой его применить нельзя.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая, скорее всего, пропущена:

У нас в Блудовом болоте эти холмы, **песчаные, покрытые высоким бором,** называют боринами.

Запятых в этом предложении и так много, поэтому **увеличивать их количество не стоит**, а лучше бы даже сократить, например:

У нас в Блудовом болоте **эти песчаные, покрытые высоким бором холмы**  называют боринами.

Но править писателя-классика мы не будем.

Comment: Но всё-таки запятая в первом случае факультативна?

Comment: Скорее ошибочна.

Comment: Формально уточнение возможно,  но зачем оно здесь нужно? Выбор делается с учетом семантики контекста и структуры данного предложения. Семантика понятна и без уточнения. у нас в Блудовом болоте - это  "в нашем Блудовом болоте". И структура данного предложения для обособления не подходит, там и так достаточно запятых. Нужно просматривать интонацию всего предложения, а не его отдельных частей.

Answer (score 2):

> > У нас, в Блудовом болоте, ...

А в таких случаях вы тоже хотите обособлять? *У нас, дома,... У нас, на работе, ...* и т.п.?

Это обособление не нужно.

И запятая перед "песчаные" тоже не нужна. Здесь простая инверсия: *песчаные холмы -> холмы песчаные*. У Пришвина встречаются подобные инверсии.

Comment: Здесь имеется в виду уточнение, которое всё-таки от интонации зависит.  Но в тех вариантах, которые Вы привели в пример, запятую, конечно, достаточно сложно поставить.